# How to keep executing code after a Documents.add in VBA (Word 2016)?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In our office we are currently using templates containing macro's. We are about to upgrade to Office 2016, but unfortunately the macro's don't work completely as they used to.

The current implentation is that a template is opened from a custom dialogue, and that a `Document_New()` is called in the template. This does not seem to work anymore: the `Document_New()` is only called when a template is opened from the file explorer, not when it's opened by a `Documents.Add()` in another macro.

Alternatively, I found a lot of solutions where `Documents.Add` is called, and then other functions are being invoked on that new document. For example

```
Set doc = Documents.Add(Template:=strSkeuze, NewTemplate:=True)
Call MsgBox(doc.Name)
```

In Word 2016 this doesn't seem to work. The `MsgBox` isn't invoked and when I step through the code in debugging mode, the code stops executing after the `Documents.Add()`.

However I cannot find anywhere that this is a known change and I am looking for a workaround to still execute  code, either from the template  like with the `Document_New()` or from the parent Macro that opens the document.

Could someone tell me whether this is still possible and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be able to detect the added document using the Application's Document_New event, either that it fires (presuming that you have been using the Document's Document_New event) or by generating the event artificially by counting open documents on the first action taken after the document is added.